# how to cast bigint to prevent sql injection in php?

Tags: php, mysql, casting, sql-injection, bigint

i am using php and running sql queries on a mysql server.
in order to prevent sql injections, i am using mysql_real_escape_string.

i am also using (int) for numbers casting, in the following manner:

```
$desired_age = 12;
$query = "select id from users where (age > ".(int)$desired_age.")";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

that work.

But, when the variable contains larger numbers, casting them fails since they are larger than int.

```
$user_id = 5633847511239487;
$query = "select age from users where (id = ".(int)$user_id.")";
$result = mysql_query($query);
// this will not produce the desired result, 
// since the user_id is actually being cast to int
```

**Is there another way to cast large number** (like BIGINT), except for the use of mysql_real_escape_string, when is comes to sql injection prevention?

Comment: there's a gotcha in this too $user_id = 5633847511239487; won't hold what you think, and there's no way tog et that number bigint back out, you'd need to keep it as a string, not an int - $user_id = '5633847511239487';

Comment: Instead of dealing with the hassles of sanitizing inputs, use parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html shows you how in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$user_id);
```

to replace all non numeric symbols in your string.
But there actually is no need to do so, simply use mysql_real_escape_string() as your integer value will be converted to a string anyway once $query is built.

Comment: ...just posting this in contrast to is_numeric wich also allows float values like "1.12" which might not exactly be what yehuda wanted :)

Comment: i tested the preg_replace solution and found that it is limited to 14 characters.
and so i am using the mysql_real_escape_string for both string and numeric user inputs.
tnx everybody

Answer (score 11):

If you are generating the user ID yourself there is no need to cast it for MySQL since there is no chance of SQL injection or other string issues.

If it is a user submitted value then use [`filter_var()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) (or [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/is_numeric)) to verify it is a number and not a string.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing, casting is useful but only for things like numerics in querystrings that are not the result of user input.  It stops people manipulating the querystring.  As for user input, checking if value is numeric is the best option as it allows you to give friendly messages.

Answer (score 1):

Validate input. Don't just simply escape it, validate it, if it's a number. There're couple of PHP functions which do the trick, like is_numeric() - Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string

http://www.php.net/is_numeric

Answer (score 1):

Use server-side prepared, parametrized statements (and thus remove the need for xyz_real_escape_string()) and/or treat the id as a string. The MySQL server has built-in rules for string<->number conversions and if you should decide to change to type/structure of the id field you don't have to change the php code as well. Unless you have concrete needs for (micro-)optimization there's usually no need to let the code make this kind of assumptions about the structure and value range of an id field in the database.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:...');
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT age FROM users WHERE id=?');
$stmt->execute(array('5633847511239487'));
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've come to such setup

```
private function escapeInt($value)
{
    if (is_float($value))
    {
        return number_format($value, 0, '.', ''); // may lose precision on big numbers
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/^-?[0-9]+$/', $value))
    {
        return (string)$value;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->error("Invalid value");
    }
}
```

Separate case for the floats because `$i = 184467440737095;` become float on a 32-bit system and thus will crumble to scientific notation when cast to string.
And simple regexp for the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can even multiply the variable by `*1`, you can check it min and max values you can accept (for age bigint is not an option at all... so why even allow numbers more than values you are prepared for?
And there is also PDO with its query preparing.